# Django. Как нормально сделать checkbox на странице и сохранять данные из него без нажатия на кнопку

Tags: python, django, django-model, django-view

### Я делаю toodoo лист такого типа

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответственно, "Add item" добавляет саму задачу с чекбоксом. Как правильно обозначить чекбокс в форме и модели и как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на чекбокс, происходило его сохранение, без нажатия каких-либо кнопок

### Мой код

#### index.html

```
            {% for task in tasks %}
            {% if task.whichList == list_name %}
        <div class="tasks">
            <div class="task">
                 <!--этот чекбокс-->
                <input type="checkbox" id="{{task.pk}}">
                <label for="{{task.pk}}">
                    <span class="custom_checkbox"></span>{{task}}
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

        <div class="new-task-creator">

            <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ itemForm }}
                <input class="btn item" type="submit"
                        aria-label="create new item" name="additem"
                       value="+">
            </form>

        </div>
```

#### forms.py

```
class AddItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(label="", max_length=40, widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
        'type': 'text', 'class': 'new item', 'placeholder': 'Add item',
    'aria-label': 'add list'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Createtask
        fields = ['title']
```

#### models.py

```
class Createtask(models.Model):
    whichList = models.ForeignKey(CreateList,
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', default=datetime.datetime.now())


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

#### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from toodooLogic.forms import AddListForm, AddGroupForm, AddItemForm
from toodooLogic.models import Createtask, CreateGroupOfTasks, CreateList

def add_new_list_view(request, pk_group, list_name):
    pk_group = CreateGroupOfTasks.objects.get(pk=pk_group)
    list_name = CreateList.objects.get(title=list_name)
    form = AddListForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'additem' in request.POST:
            form3 = AddItemForm(request.POST or None)
            if form3.is_valid():
                new_task = form3.save(commit=False)
                new_task.whichList = list_name
                new_task.save()
        return redirect(request.path)

    context = {
        'listForm': AddListForm,
        'groupForm': AddGroupForm,
        'itemForm': AddItemForm,
        'tasks': Createtask.objects.all(),
        'groups': CreateGroupOfTasks.objects.all(),
        'lists': CreateList.objects.all(),
        'list_name': list_name
    }

    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

#### Прошу прощения за говнокод. Лишние куски кода постарался убрать для удобства просмотра.

Answer (score 1):

Относительно сохранения, если я правильно понял вопсрос, Вам нужно отправить "фоново" запрос. Для этого можно использовать AJAX к примеру. Повесить обработку события на нажатие определенной секции и отправлять данные на бекенд нужной функции.
Для этого можно добавить общий class для всех чекбоксов, далее по этому классу ловить нажатие, брать id выбранного элеменета и отправлять. К примеру

```
<input type="checkbox" id="{{task.pk}}" class="task">
$('.task').on('click', function(){    # перехватили нажатие на элемент
task_id = $(this).attr('id')   # получили id выбранного элемента
data = {task_id: task_id}
$.ajax({    type: "GET",
            url: '{% url "remove_task" %}', # remove_task - нужный url
            data: data,
success: function(data){
# здесь можно выполнить визуальные изменения
}
```